# An issue with CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath drawing circle counterclockwise

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm trying to draw a circle that starts and ends at 12 o'clock counterclockwise. The issue I'm having is that the shape is not being drawn.
Im' using `init(arcCenter center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool)` initializer for the path and if I use `clockwise: true`, it works. If `startAngle` is set to `0` and `endAngle` to `2 * .pi` it works with `clockwise: false`. However combination of `clockwise: false` and `startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: 1.5 * .pi` doesn't work. Is there a reason for this and how can I fix it?

This one works:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let arcCenter = view.center
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: false)
shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
shapeLayer.fillColor = .none
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

And this one. Results look the same.

```
UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 100, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: 1.5 * .pi, clockwise: true)
```

[image: Success]

But not this one:

```
UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 100, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: 1.5 * .pi, clockwise: false)
```

[image: Failed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier to think about this in degrees.

- `-0.5 * .pi` radians equals `-90` degrees
- `1.5 * .pi` radians equals `270` degrees
- `0` degrees is at the middle-right of the circle

However, if you think about it, `-90` and `270` are at the same position on the circle.

---

`clockwise = true`:

```
UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 100, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: 1.5 * .pi, clockwise: true)
```

[image]

`clockwise = false`:

```
UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 100, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: 1.5 * .pi, clockwise: false)
```

[image]

So how come `clockwise` draws the long way, but counterclockwise doesn't? Take a look at this:
[image: gradually increasing arc angles]

If you pick two points (or you could say angles) on the circle and gradually increase one of them, you can see how the ring lengthens/shortens based on whether it's going `clockwise`/`counterclockwise`. The rings complement each other -- if you put the `clockwise` ring on top of the `counterclockwise` one, they fit perfectly together in a circle.

So, when you increase the ending point so that it's the equivalent of the starting point (`start: -90, end: 270`):

- the `clockwise` ring will be full
- the `counterclockwise` ring will be empty

whereas when you switch the negatives (`start: 90, end: -270`):

- the `clockwise` ring will be empty
- the `counterclockwise` ring will be full

---

Also, here's a handy [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/14351818) (thanks @Leo Dabus!) so you don't have to deal with radians anymore:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { CGFloat(self) * .pi / 180 }
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}

/// usage:
UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 100, startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
```

Comment: whats the difference from `0*.pi` to  `2*.pi` and `1*.pi` to `3*.pi`? I don't get it. `-90` and `270` are not the same angle. If that were true `0` and `360` would be as well.

Comment: Yes, -90 and 270 are not the same angle, but if you put it on a circle, it's the same location. 0 is at the right-middle, and you can either go left (negative) or right (positive)

Comment: I see what you mean. The solution here is to use `-0.5 * .pi, endAngle: -2.5 * .pi` if he needs to use clockwise `false`

Comment: This extension looks familiar. :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/2303865

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you.

Comment: @LeoDabus wait, it's yours! I've been using it in my projects for so long. Sorry I didn't credit, I'll edit

Comment: @aheze I still I don't understand why you can cross the zero clockwise while you can't cross it counter clockwise. It doesn't make any sense to me. It should behave the same.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, but I think it's because there needs to be a way to fill the entire circle, or leave it blank. I did some tests, though: [Normal](https://imgur.com/a/U3QjPbm), [20 added to start angle](https://imgur.com/a/TsDA1tL), [20 subtracted from start angle](https://imgur.com/a/UlEHXgP). I'm trying to make sense of it.

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, I think I got it. Here's some [screenshots](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z8CEDkJJwdQ1matrX8IqVRzoTE-0Tp-J/view?usp=sharing). If you gradually increase/decrease the angles, you can see how it's opposite depending on clockwise/counterclockwise

Comment: This illustrates it better. The arcs complements each other. So none is the complement of full. Y9u should add this info to your post.

Comment: So if the value increases clockwise will be full if the value decreases counterclockwise will be full. That totally makes sense to me now.