# Clockwise or counterclockwise in adding Arc for path in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

It is a common knowledge about clockwise or counterclockwise, like this picture:

[image]

So when I read clockwise set to true it means it is clockwise, and if I read clockwise set to false it means counterclockwise. However, as you can read in the code below, I set clockwise to true, but the result is not correct.

Is it a wrong function coding from Apple?

Test code:

```
struct CircleShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: 200,
                        startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can read in my code, I set clockwise for true, starting from 0 and end for 90, but the output is for `clockwise: false` which is not what I understand from clockwise or counterclockwise. Is it not confusing behavior? Or, I am missing something in between?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be wrong coded :))

Comment: @vadian  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64272159/2303865

Comment: My question got closed for unknown reason! Those links does not answer my question, I am still looking to an answer.

Comment: It is about Z vector direction (around which rotation of clock is performed), but vector is not from you (as you see), but to you, so you see it as opposite.

Comment: but no one is going ask me about axes when I use the word of clockwise, the word of clockwise has own definition globally, unless they could use better naming for avoid such misunderstanding. I would say it is wrong naming if it is not wrong coding.

Comment: The addArc docs say a "vertically-flipped coordinate system" is used. So it helps to imagine that the whole thing is flipped along the x axis. Read the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225735